# Streaming video from URL with Authorization in header

Tags: ios, stream, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I have probably quick question but I couldn't find the right answer. I have a method on server that get a mp4 file. The problem is that I must Authorize the connection by the token.

How to stream video by AVPlayerViewController or MPMoviePlayerViewController with Authorization in header?

I will be glad for help

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C you can use `AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey` OR `AVURLAssetHTTPCookiesKey`

From the reference of [Swift dev forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31646), it's not possible at the moment.